# CentOS 7.0 docker fail to start service

Tags: linux, docker, centos, centos7

I work with CentOS 7.0, and trying to configure docker, i used `yum install docker` for the docker installation.
when I start docker service, meets the follow problems:

```
[root@kiiby2r3 ~]# systemctl start docker.service
Job for docker.service failed. See 'systemctl status docker.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.



[root@kiiby2r3 ~]# systemctl status docker.service -l
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sun 2015-11-08 12:52:13 CST; 1h 3min ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 30368

Nov 08 12:48:35 kiiby2r3 docker[30368]: time="2015-11-08T12:48:35.968317600+08:00" level=info msg="Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)"
Nov 08 12:48:36 kiiby2r3 docker[30368]: time="2015-11-08T12:48:36.028124500+08:00" level=error msg="WARNING: No --storage-opt dm.thinpooldev specified, using loopback; this configuration is strongly discouraged for production use"
Nov 08 12:49:34 kiiby2r3 systemd[1]: docker.service operation timed out. Terminating.
Nov 08 12:51:04 kiiby2r3 systemd[1]: docker.service stopping timed out (2). Killing.
Nov 08 12:52:13 kiiby2r3 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Nov 08 12:52:14 kiiby2r3 systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
```

The CentOS release version:

```
[root@kiiby2r3 ~]# uname -a
Linux kiiby2r3 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 30 12:09:22 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@kiiby2r3 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)
```

Can somebody give me a hint?

Thank you!

Comment: Try to disable SElinux, and if it solves the issue then add the SErules to allow the service,

Comment: We hit a bug with docker-selinux 1.8 that requires a reboot after upgrading.